# Which aspect do you find is the hardest to deliver as a parent?

Tags: discussion, survey

I am looking for parents to share feedback around some of their current needs. If you have time, can you complete this 2-minute survey https://joinhomeroom.wufoo.com/forms/wub4dck1dyd63n/?

Comment: Thank you for moving it to the right group!

Comment: This survey is rather poorly set up. A lot of possible answers are missing from the multiple choice section and the questions about finance are meaningless unless you know the geographic location of the answerers.